# How to display textboxes one under another without shifting?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<div>
    <p><label>Faculty <input type="text" class = "f"></label></p>
    <p><label >Department<input type="text" class = "f"></label></p>
</div>
```

How can I make textboxes appear one under another without shifting?

Comment: study css width property.  Fix your spelling of Department!

Comment: Why are you wrapping each `<label>` in a `<p>`? Yes, it's allowed; but it seems contrary to the use of semantics, given that a labelled input doesn't really qualify as a 'paragraph.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `inline-block`, additional `<span>` tags added.

```css
div > p > label > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            <span>Faculty</span>
            <input type="text" class="f" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <span>Department</span>
            <input type="text" class="f" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Or, the css table way.

```css
div > p > label {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
div > p > label > span {
    display: table-cell;
}
div > p > label > span:first-child {
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            <span>Faculty</span>
            <span><input type="text" class="f" /></span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <span>Department</span>
            <span><input type="text" class="f" /></span>
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

give a left margin to your input field for faculty

Comment: @omeinusch: it's not a great answer, but it *is* a valid (if wrong/incomplete) answer to the question.